# Sed replace ; with | but ignore ; inside quotes

Tags: sed, replace

I want to replace `;` inside a file with `|` but ignore semicolons inside a double quote. I want to perform the operation on the same file using `sed -I` option

input:  `1;2;"3;4;5"`

expected output: `1|2|"3;4;5`

Comment: No, you don't want to do this with sed.

Comment: What is the best way to do it then?

Comment: Write a simple state machine that reads one byte at a time and has 2 states.  Start in state "repl".  If you see a quote, change state.  If you see a `;` and are in the state "repl", output a `|`. Otherwise, output the character you read.

Comment: What do you want to do with the input `1;2"3;\n;4;5;6` (unmatched quotes) or `1;2;"\n";3;4";5\n"` (matched quotes spread over multiple lines)?

Comment: Something more flexible than a regex engine. The awk solution is OK; a proper CSV parser would be best, but I'm having trouble getting python's to keep the (now unnecessary) quotes around the "3;4;5"

Answer (score 0):

GNU **`AWK`** solution:

Sample `input.txt` file:

```
1;2;"3;4;5"
6;"7;8;9";10
```

---

The job:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^;]+|"[^"]+"' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF? ORS:OFS) }' OFS='|' input.txt
```

The output:

```
1|2|"3;4;5"
6|"7;8;9"|10
```